# Payouts in PayPal SDK for .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, paypal, payment

Im looking at the new [Paypal SDK for .NET Core](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/tree/2.0-beta) (which is in beta) and I cand find Pay**outs** (not to be confused with Payments). Does anybody know if its just not developed yet or if its replaced by something else. I want to transfer money from my Paypal acccount to another Paypal account. Do I need to use the non-Core-version or just use [their REST api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/) for that?

Hope this was clear enough :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for PayPal developer support, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not implemented on Core but it is on Framework. Either use that or the REST api as you say.

Comment: Ok, sweet. Better to know so I can make the extra effort without there is a simple solution that I missed. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please give us a link to .net framework paypal sdk in which are implemented payouts?